# Python: Scraping a classifieds site. How to return only newest entries from last run?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'd like to keep an eye on a classifieds listing page and have it ping me whenever something new shows up. I've built a fairly naive scraper in bs4 that grabs a single page and scrapes the item, price and when that item was listed.

Something along the lines of

```
page = requests.get('https://sg.carousell.com/search/products/?collection_id=13&query=herman%20miller&sort_by=time_created%2Cdescending')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
for item in soup.find_all(class_='_-W'):
  item.find(class_='_-m').text
  item.find(class_='_-t').text
```

At which point I'll hook it up to some bot and I'll get a ping each time the job runs.

However I only want to be alerted when something new shows up. One option would be to store the first item found in some way (e.g. as txt) and then compare the unique ID of each item. If an item has a higher ID than the previous run then it must be new.

However I feel like this is a bit clunky and wonder what other options are available. Tracking new items in a list between runs sounds like a problem that surely has been solved many times but I'm failing to discover any solutions in my searching.

Comment: You could use a simple sqlite3 database that is included in python. You could store datestamps and any other information you need to compare and determine which is the newest.

Answer (score 0):

Since you run your scraper periodically you can look at the 'time' and understand if its new or not.

```
<time class="_-t"><span>5 days ago</span></time>
```